# How to insert rows depending on previous row meeting conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I have a simplified file (foo.csv),

**Contents of foo:**

```
['MyNum', 'Cycle', 'Line', 'V1', 'V2', 'T1']
['1', 'C', '1', '6.7', '25.6', '90']
['3', 'A', '1', '5.8', '22.5', '89.9']
['3', 'A', '2', '5.8', '24.2', '90']
['3', 'A', '3', '5.8', '25.4', '90']
['5', 'B', '1', '6', '25.3', '89.9']
['5', 'B', '2', '6.3', '23.8', '89.9']
['7', 'C', '1', '7.1', '24', '89.9']
['7', 'C', '2', '9999', '9111', '9333']
['7', 'C', '3', '9999', '9111', '9333']
```

What I want to have is 3 rows each having the same first item (MyNum) but their third item (Line) incrementing from 1 to 3. So if I only have 1 or 2 rows with that MyNum first term value I need to insert either one or two rows, each of which is the same as the row above it except for the Line term which should increment.

**Desired output:**

```
['MyNum', 'Cycle', 'Line', 'V1', 'V2', 'T1']
['1', 'C', '1', '6.7', '25.6', '90']
['1', 'C', '2', '6.7', '25.6', '90']
['1', 'C', '3', '6.7', '25.6', '90']
['3', 'A', '1', '5.8', '22.5', '89.9']
['3', 'A', '2', '5.8', '24.2', '90']
['3', 'A', '3', '5.8', '25.4', '90']
['5', 'B', '1', '6', '25.3', '89.9']
['5', 'B', '2', '6.3', '23.8', '89.9']
['5', 'B', '3', '6.3', '23.8', '89.9']
['7', 'C', '1', '7.1', '24', '89.9']
['7', 'C', '2', '9999', '9111', '9333']
['7', 'C', '3', '9999', '9111', '9333']
```

**Code**

```
import csv
data = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print('\n'*5)

print(df["MyNum"])
"""
for i in df["MyNum"]:
    if i+1 = i
    print(i)
"""
with open('foo.csv', 'r') as f_in, open('__fooOut.csv', 'w') as f_out:  # this creates a new output file in write mode
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',') # modify for your file
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',') # modify for your file
    num = 0
    num_count = 3
    while num_count > 0:
        for row in reader:
            print(row)


"""
Manual method

The first item in the first row is 1 and a third item 1.
The following three rows have a first item of 3 and their third items go from 
1, 2 to 3.
The following two rows have a first item of 5 and their third items go from 
1 to 2.
The following 3 rows have a first item of 7 and their third items go from 
1, 2 to 3.

What should happen is there should be three rows each having the same first 
item, and when they do their third item (row[2] or "Line") should increment and
 be either a 1, 2 or 3.
When there is not two rows with the same first item as the row above a new row
 should be inserted immediately below the row with the same details as the 
 row above except for the third item.
"""
```

I don't know how to do this, whether the approach should be a dataframe or not,
nor how to check that the next row's first item is equal to the row under test.

Comment: the `complete` function in `pyjanitor` simplifies this; @jezrael's solution is apt, so no need for extras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If input data are integers for `Line` column use custom lambda function with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'` for forward filling not existed values in range `1,4` like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')

f = lambda x: x.reindex(range(1, 4), method='ffill')
df = (df.set_index('Line')
        .groupby(['MyNum','Cycle'])
        .apply(f)
        .drop(['MyNum','Cycle'], 1)
        .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (df)
    MyNum Cycle  Line      V1      V2      T1
0       1     C     1     6.7    25.6    90.0
1       1     C     2     6.7    25.6    90.0
2       1     C     3     6.7    25.6    90.0
3       3     A     1     5.8    22.5    89.9
4       3     A     2     5.8    24.2    90.0
5       3     A     3     5.8    25.4    90.0
6       5     B     1     6.0    25.3    89.9
7       5     B     2     6.3    23.8    89.9
8       5     B     3     6.3    23.8    89.9
9       7     C     1     7.1    24.0    89.9
10      7     C     2  9999.0  9111.0  9333.0
11      7     C     3  9999.0  9111.0  9333.0
```

Comment: I have no idea how that is working but it works fine, I have a lot to learn today. Thank you jezrael.